# Unity EditorGUILayout IntSlider wont work

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine, slider, editor

Hey i want to create a Editor NavMesh Waypoint Path that the Developer can actually see. I wanted to use IntSliders for my values because it's easyer to work with instead of textfields but they are not moving like they are freezing.

Before i added the sliders everything worked like expected, so i dont know where the mistake is, or i can't see it.

[image]

Here is my code, do i miss something?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEditor;




    [CustomEditor(typeof(AIWaypointNetwork))]
    public class AIWaypointNetworkEditor : Editor 
    {
        public override void OnInspectorGUI()
        {
            AIWaypointNetwork network = (AIWaypointNetwork)target;

            network.DisplayMode = (PathDisplayMode)EditorGUILayout.EnumPopup("Display Mode", network.DisplayMode);

            if (network.DisplayMode == PathDisplayMode.Paths)
            {
                network.UIStart = EditorGUILayout.IntSlider("Waypoint Start", network.UIStart, 0, network.Waypoints.Count - 1);
                network.UIStart = EditorGUILayout.IntSlider("Waypoint End", network.UIEnd, 0, network.Waypoints.Count - 1);
            }
            DrawDefaultInspector();
        }

        void OnSceneGUI()
        {
            AIWaypointNetwork network = (AIWaypointNetwork)target;

            for (int i=0; i<network.Waypoints.Count; i++) 
            {
                if (network.Waypoints[i] != null)
                    Handles.Label (network.Waypoints [i].position, "Waypoint " + i.ToString ());
            }

            if (network.DisplayMode == PathDisplayMode.Connections)
            {
                Vector3[] linePoints = new Vector3[network.Waypoints.Count + 1];

                for (int i = 0; i <= network.Waypoints.Count; i++)
                {
                    int index = i != network.Waypoints.Count ? i : 0;
                    if (network.Waypoints [index] != null)
                        linePoints [i] = network.Waypoints [index].position;
                    else
                        linePoints [i] = new Vector3 (Mathf.Infinity, Mathf.Infinity, Mathf.Infinity);
                }
                Handles.color = Color.cyan;
                Handles.DrawPolyLine (linePoints);
            } 
            else 
            if (network.DisplayMode == PathDisplayMode.Paths) 
            {
                NavMeshPath path = new NavMeshPath();

                if(network.Waypoints[network.UIStart]!=null && network.Waypoints[network.UIEnd]!=null)
                {
                    Vector3 from = network.Waypoints[network.UIStart].position;
                    Vector3 to = network.Waypoints[network.UIEnd].position;

                    NavMesh.CalculatePath(from, to, NavMesh.AllAreas, path);
                    Handles.color = Color.yellow;
                    Handles.DrawPolyLine(path.corners);
                }
            }
        }
    }



using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public enum PathDisplayMode { None, Connections, Paths }

public class AIWaypointNetwork : MonoBehaviour 
{ 
    [HideInInspector]
    public PathDisplayMode DisplayMode = PathDisplayMode.Connections;

    [HideInInspector]
    public int UIStart = 0;

    [HideInInspector]
    public int UIEnd = 0;

    public List<Transform> Waypoints = new List<Transform> ();

}
```

Comment: Check this line for accuracy: `network.UIStart = EditorGUILayout.IntSlider("Waypoint End", network.UIEnd, 0, network.Waypoints.Count - 1);`

Comment: i did, it's fine

Comment: no it was not fine, i copy paste the first and only changed everything after the = but forget to change the name of the variable to the right on...

Answer (score 0):

The problem was:

```
network.UIStart = EditorGUILayout.IntSlider("Waypoint Start", network.UIStart, 0, network.Waypoints.Count - 1);

network.UIStart = EditorGUILayout.IntSlider("Waypoint End", network.UIEnd, 0, network.Waypoints.Count - 1);
```

i forget to change the second variable to UIEnd...

The solution is:

```
network.UIStart = EditorGUILayout.IntSlider("Waypoint Start", network.UIStart, 0, network.Waypoints.Count - 1);

network.UIEnd = EditorGUILayout.IntSlider("Waypoint End", network.UIEnd, 0, network.Waypoints.Count - 1);
```

Comment: There's a close reason called "off-topic: problem was due to a typo." As such, this question should be closed, not answered.